# Cannot set property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I got some error please help me. I did check out f12 the error message :

> TypeError: Cannot set property `innerHTML` of `null` << like this

Apologies for my English.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
 <body>
<div class="js-clock"></div>
<h1>00:00</h1>
<script type ="text/javascript">
const clockContainer=document.querySelector(".js-clock") ,
clockTitle =clockContainer.querySelector("h1");

function getTime() {
const date = new Date();
const minutes = date.getMinutes();
const hours = date.getHours();
clockTitle.innerText =`${hours}:${minutes}`;


}

function  init() {
getTime();

} 
init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`clockContainer` is a element and you are using [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

> The `querySelector()` method of the Element interface returns the first element that is a **descendant of the element on which it is invoked** that matches the specified group of selectors.

`clockContainer.querySelector("h1");` will return `<h1>` element inside `clockContainer`. You should wrap the `<div>` around `<h1>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
 <body>
<div class="js-clock">
<h1>00:00</h1>
</div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    const clockContainer=document.querySelector(".js-clock") ,
    clockTitle =clockContainer.querySelector("h1");

    function getTime() {
      const date = new Date();
      const minutes = date.getMinutes();
      const hours = date.getHours();
      clockTitle.innerText =`${hours}:${minutes}`;  
    }

    function  init() {
      getTime();

    } 
    init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking the *h1* element inside the *div* element, but it is outside of the div. Place the *h1* element inside the div.

```js
const clockContainer=document.querySelector(".js-clock") ,
clockTitle =clockContainer.querySelector("h1");

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  clockTitle.innerText =`${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

function  init() {
  getTime();
} 
init();
```

```html
<div class="js-clock">
  <h1>00:00</h1>
</div>
```

If you do not want *h1* inside the *div* then you can access the element directly from *document*.

```js
clockTitle = document.querySelector("h1");

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  clockTitle.innerText =`${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

function  init() {
  getTime();
} 
init();
```

```html
<div class="js-clock"></div>
<h1>00:00</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the other answers, if you don't need `clockContainer` for anything else you can target the `h1` element directly in the `querySelector` and skip that extra step.

```js
// Target the h1 in the element with the js-clock class
const clockTitle = document.querySelector('.js-clock h1');

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  clockTitle.innerText = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

getTime();
```

```html
<div class="js-clock">
  <h1>00:00</h1>
</div>
```